# Cannot override compareTo

Tags: python, eclipse, maven

### Java maven project on Eclipse IDE

maven-resources-plugin 2.7

JDK/JRE 13

Eclipse EE 4.15

### Structure

```
public interface Frequency {
    public int increment();
    public int decrement();
    public int freq();
    public Object getTop();
}
```

The following class needs to implement the interfaces Freq

```
public class Child extends IndexedWord implements Frequency{
int freq;
TreeSet<Relation> relations;
public Child() {
    freq=0;
    relations = new TreeSet<Relation>(new FreqCompare<Relation>());
}

public void addRelation(Relation relation) {
    relations.add(relation);
}

public Relation getTop() {
    Relation top=relations.first();
    top.decrement();
    return top;
}

@Override
public int increment() {
    freq++;
    return freq;
}
@Override
public int decrement() {
    freq--;
    return freq;
}

@Override
public int freq() {
    return freq;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

### The bug

Eclipse refuses to compile the project. When hovering over the declaration of compareTO(), I get

> the method compareTo(Object) must override or implement a supertype
> method

### What I tried

Using a different JDK version

Rebuilding the  .settings, .classpath, .project files/folders

### Edit: Solution

I modified the Class to implement both Frequency and Comparable

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java language specification, it's an **error** to have **`@Override` for a method that does not override or implement** something.

In your case, you have to remove the implementation of this method or at least the `@Override` annotation to get valid Java code or change the code that the method overrides or implements something, e.g. by adding the add `Comparable` interface (e.g. as `Frequency extends Comparable` or as `Child extends IndexedWord implements Frequency, Comparable` or as `IndexedWord implements Comparable` or ...).

Comment: Thanks. I just had to add the Comparable<> Interface

Comment: Yes, e.g. you can also add the Comparable interface as `Frequency extends Comparable` or `Child extends IndexedWord implements Frequency, Comparable` or `IndexedWord implements Comparable` or ...

Comment: Frequency extends Comparable is broken:

Comment: The interface Comparable cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments Comparable<GrammaticalRelation> and Comparable

Comment: But Child extends IndexedWord implements Frequency, Comparable<IndexedWord> is fine

Comment: This is a design decision, what you want to compare. With `Comparable<IndexedWord>` the method becomes `public int compareTo(IndexedWord otherIndexedWord) { ...`